# React does not update when content is nested in array (i have made sure that the state update)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested

The problem i have is that React does not update in the situation below.
I added a forceUpdate() when the component should update just to make extra sure.

The code is simple so there is not much to say.
It's as if React does not see that it should update or am i doing something really wrong here?

```
class Greetings extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.switchLanguage = this.switchLanguage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      languageID: 0,
    }
    
    this.arrayContainingRenderValues = [
        <span>{this.props.greetingArray[this.state.languageID]}!</span>,
        <span>No greetings for you!!</span>
      
    ]
  }
  
  switchLanguage(){
    this.setState((previousState) => ({languageID: (previousState.languageID + 1) % this.props.greetingArray.length}))
    
    
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.timerID = setInterval(this.switchLanguage, 500)
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.timerID)
  }
  
  render(){
    return this.arrayContainingRenderValues[0]

    //The return below works without problem
    return <span>{this.props.greetingArray[this.state.languageID]}!</span>
  }
}


let content = <Greetings greetingArray={["Good morning","Bonjour","Buenos días","Guten tag","Bom dia","Buongiorno"]}/>

ReactDOM.render(content, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The state gets updated, you can see that simply by commenting out the first return.

Comment: `this.arrayContainingRenderValues` is just an array of 2 React elements, which is only set once, in the constructor. I'm not sure how you expect React to "know" to update it when the state used in calculating it changes. There are many better ways of handling this, but the simplest change to make it work is the one you've already got in your second `return`, which you admit works - so I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: `componentWillDismount` is not a thing.  You want `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Found it strange that this code does not work I assumed that because the state was used in `<span>{this.props.greetingArray[this.state.languageID]}!</span>` and that it was called from the `render()` it would update the dom like any other react code. I was trying react and it just works it's amazing and I guess I wanted to see the limits.

Answer (score 0):

A i got an answer, it is just that the value of the content in `this.arrayContainingRenderValues[]` was computed and then fixed when first assigned inside the `constructor()`, to have it recompute the array had to be reassigned in the `render()`.

So in the end i may as well not use the array at all. 
But i just wanted to test how react works thanks for the help.